# Each time I do restart - Windows 8 resets my settings/registry to some state

Tags: windows-8, reboot

I have Windows 8 PRO 64 bit for 3-4 months.

At some point, Windows started to abandon system changes that I make, after Restart or after Shutdown+Start. It stopped saving my files associations. All the old associations are good, but all the new ones returns to the default ones, each time after restart. Also it abandons some other registry based data (I think), as the password of Goggle Drive (that I installed after this point), and Foxit Reader (that I installed after this point too) is always asking me to choose tabbed/classic interface, as if I've just installed it.

I didn't install any State Freezer software. I permit windows to update itself regullary. I have updated Eset Nod32 AV.

What could be the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: It happened to me once that when I started my computer (Windows 9 Pro), it just reset all my settings and somehow got me to a clear Start menu, no trace of me ever using it after I made the account. I rebooted instantly when that happened and it seemed to have solved itself, however it is a strange issue.

Comment: @Bogdacutu: What's even more strange us how you managed to get your hands on Windows 9 Pro! ;)

Comment: @Karan: lol, I just noticed. I meant Windows 8 Pro, but it's too late to edit now :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to create a new user.

Looks like the user profile gets a little bit corrupted and bombs out. I created new user and it saved all changes I made.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Richard. Answers are meant for providing actual solutions to the question. Your previously deleted answers didn't contain that – only a placeholder for the issues you were having and what you were going to try next. We're not really a forum, which is why those posts have been deleted. You could have also edited one of these posts to clarify it and then have it undeleted. But right now this one is fine to stay.

Comment: Simple, and works like a charm! :)